# How to use dotnet pack selectively on a solution

Tags: .net

I have a solution  **foo.sln**. All libraries within are SDK projects. However only one of them should be **packed**

By default

```
dotnet pack
```

tries to pack all projects. There is no exclude filter or include filter for that matter. What is the recommended process?

Comment: according to docs, you can specify either name of the project or path to it. You can also run dotnet pack from projects directory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x

Comment: I just saw. Yes I can specify the project. However does this build all the dependencies correctly or do I have to build the solution first?

Comment: Dependencies from nuget go to .nuspec file. As for project-to-project docs say: 
Currently, you must have a package per project if you have project-to-project dependencies.

Comment: I'm using new SDK project file format. There are no nuspec files anymore.

Comment: But my main issue was excluding the build of unit test libraries as nuget packages. 50% are libs that need to be packed and 50% are test libs that should not. With all the automation now in the dotnet command some kind of filtering looks like an oversight.

Comment: well, I cannot hepl you more. What's more weird, docs say taht there is an argument --no-dependencies, that excludes them. That's confusing :)

Answer (score 46):

You select what project to pack as nuget package by setting property inside of `csproj` file, like this:

`<IsPackable>true</IsPackable>` - create package

`<IsPackable>false</IsPackable>` - don't create package

If you don't want to specify it in each file you can create a text file named `Directory.Build.props` in the directory with the following content:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

It would be automatically included in all on the beginning of the SDK project file (csproj) in this and all nested folders, so you can specify common default values for this group of projects and if needed they could be overridden in individual csproj files.

If you don't want them to be overwritten or need to use some values defined in csproj, you should use file name `Directory.Build.targets`, that would be automatically included at the end of csproj.

In our projects we use the following structure:

```
 \
   \src
      <actual projects>
      Directory.Build.props
   \tests
      <unit tests>
      Directory.Build.props
   Directory.Build.props
   MySolution.sln
```

In this way, we are able to specify different common properties for test and regular projects.

One note on this is that by default only first `Directory.Build.props`that found by `csproj` would be applied, to change this behavior you need to add this line in the beginning of nested `Directory.Build.props` files (inside of `Project` tag):

```
  <Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('$(_DirectoryBuildPropsFile)', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../'))" />
```

More about all of this could be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017