# Issue in creating NuGet package in VS 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to support NetStandard2.0 for my class library targeting the .Net framework 461. I'm able to build the application successfully. I'm following the steps given in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli) to package and publish the NuGet.I tried both CLI and Pack options. But the NuGet is not getting created. What other this should I check to generate the NuGet package OR is there any other alternative approach?

```
<PropertyGroup>
<Description></Description>
<TargetFrameworks>net461;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
<GenerateDocumentationFile>false</GenerateDocumentationFile>
<RootNamespace>Students.Library</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>Students.Library</AssemblyName>
<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
```

Comment: What exactly did you run, and what was the output? I've just tried running `dotnet pack` with your project file (plus a `Project` element outside, and a closing `</PropertyGroup>`) and it was fine. I haven't tried it in VS, but I'd generally recommend running `dotnet pack` from the command line anyway :)

Comment: Just tried it from VS using the context menu on the project, and that worked fine, including telling me (in the output window) where the NuGet package was built. Without knowing more about output you're seeing, it's hard to help any further.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the response. Finally, I fixed the issue by adding <IsPackable>true</IsPackable> . Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540851/how-to-use-dotnet-pack-selectively-on-a-solution

Comment: You really shouldn't have to though - as I said, I tried the project file you've given, and it was fine. Perhaps there were other dependencies that you haven't mentioned, that could have affected the default?